# Error deploying PHP application to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

My app is just two files: index.php and app.yaml in the same directory. I keep getting an error every time I try to deploy the application to App Engine.

Comment: That isn't a useful error, is it? Please confirm that you're using App Engine flexible (not standard)? When you say "Hello World", is it the Google tutorial (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples)? Have you enabled billing? Please try running the `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug`

Comment: Daz, my application is just an index.php file with "echo hello world" in it, and an app.yaml file with

runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: /

If I change document_root to anything else or leave it blank it gives me an error.

Comment: App Engine expects the app to be a web server. It expects to receive a container that listens on port `8080`and supports HTTP. You won't be able to deploy just `echo hello world`. Have a look at the Hello World example I included. Perhaps try that?

Comment: My app is not a web server. So the issue was with my app.yaml file. Apparently you can't have it in the same dir as your app so I did this: client > app > web > index.php + client > app > app.yaml and in app.yaml I changed it to document_web: web - Everything works and the website is functioning correctly now.

Comment: Post your solution with explanations as an answer to help others with similar problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did, thanks.

Comment: Where did you post the answer? Do not post the solution in the question, post an answer.

Comment: John, my apologies. I've been out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your file structure has to be a certain way.

- [folder1/] <directory you gcloud init from
- [folder1/web/] <where your index.php file is
- [folder1/app.yaml] <your app.yaml file should be in the main "folder1" directory

index.php

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
```

Maybe this isn't correct but it's the only way I could make it work.